# If remove parent category the child category items willl automatically removed from cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories, product

I have a problem in WooCommerce. If I remove a parent category item from cart, the child category items willl automatically be removed from the cart? How can I do it?

[image]

Comment: @LoicTheAztec i've shared a screenshot.pls check this

Comment: Not clear (Excuse me) 1) Do you want if in cart you have for example 2 items (one with parent category and the other with child) to remove automatically the chid category item when removing parent category item... Or ... 2) the opposite (avoid that)  ??? … what one solution 1) … or … solution 2) ?

Comment: @LoicTheAztec .. when remove parent category item, child item automatically remove from cart..  we want solution 1